# How do i make ng-file-upload work with drf-chunked-upload?

Tags: django-rest-framework, ng-file-upload

So the question is basically in title, but let me provide a bit extended explanation.

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

https://github.com/jkeifer/drf-chunked-upload

As documentation says ng-file-upload assumes that we have API endpoint that will accept chunks and respond with current size of an uploaded file. drf-chunked-upload works another way - first we send a request to initialize chunked upload, server responds with an object that contains id of a new upload and then all subsequent requests are sent to a url like "http://path/to/view/{id_of_upload}".

Maybe someone already had an expirience with that?

Comment: I think you need to implement it yourself, you can chunk file in pieces using file.slice() and then use Upload.upload() to send each piece to the server with the id that you get from initialization.

Comment: If you end up implementing it, it could be added to the plugin so feel free to create a PR or an issue with the required code so I could include it with the plugin.